# Symfony 4 parent abstract class does not set all its dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I have an abstract class called *CommonService* with many properties passed through the constructor and this parent class has 3 children. Until now the children had to pass these depencencies to the parent constructor each time, but I'm trying to make so that they do not have to provide the parent dependencies any more.

I made this configuration in the services.yaml file (following the official documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html):

```
 App\Service\Events\Common\CommonService:
    abstract: true
    arguments:
      - '@App\DTO\Common\Mapper\CommonEventListDTOMapper'
      - '@App\DTO\Common\Mapper\CommonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper'
      - '@App\DTO\Common\Mapper\CommonProductProcessListDTOMapper'
      - '@App\DTO\Common\Mapper\CommonEventDTOMapper'
      - '@App\Repository\Events\OutAudit\EventProcessRepository'
      - '@App\Repository\Events\OutAudit\EventProductRepository'
       // and so on

 App\Service\Events\Audit\NcService:
     parent: App\Service\Events\Common\CommonService
     autowire: true
     autoconfigure: false   
     
 App\Service\Events\OutAudit\ProcessService:
     parent: App\Service\Events\Common\CommonService
     autowire: true
     autoconfigure: false
       
 App\Service\Events\OutAudit\ProductService:
    parent: App\Service\Events\Common\CommonService
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: false
```

This abstract class has many properties, **but the issue is that only 2 dependencies are set** :

[image]

```
CommonProductProcessListDTOMapper           $commonProductProcessListDTOMapper,
CommonEventDTOMapper                        $commonEventDTOMapper
```

Implementation :

```
abstract class CommonService implements EventsInterface
{
    use DateTimeZoneTrait;

    protected EventProcessRepository $eventProcessRepository;
    protected EventProductRepository $eventProductRepository;
    protected bool $inUpdateProcess = false;
    protected OptionRepository $optionRepository;
    protected HistoryService $historyService;
    protected array $listChange = [];
    protected EntityManagerInterface $em;
    protected UserRepository $userRepository;
    protected TokenService $tokenService;
    protected UserService $userService;
    protected SupplierService $supplierService;
    protected SupplierRepository $supplierRepository;
    protected ?string $messageHistoryTrack;
    protected AttachmentService $attachmentService;
    protected SmtpService $smtpService;
    protected bool $sendMail = false;
    protected bool $sendMailOwner = false;
    protected bool $sendMailManager = false;
    protected bool $sendMailDiffusions = false;
    protected bool $sendMailApproved = false;
    protected bool $hasChangedOwner = false;
    protected ActionService $actionService;
    protected ActionRepository $actionRepository;
    protected BranchRepository $branchRepository;
    private BranchService $branchService;
    private EventRcService $eventRcService;
    private EventRepository $eventRepository;
    private CommonEventListDTOMapper $commonEventListDTOMapper;
    private CommonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper $commonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper;
    private CommonProductProcessListDTOMapper $commonProductProcessListDTOMapper;
    private CommonEventDTOMapper $commonEventDTOMapper;

    public function __construct(
        EventProcessRepository                      $eventProcessRepository,
        EventProductRepository                      $eventProductRepository,
        HistoryService                              $historyService,
        EntityManagerInterface                      $em,
        UserRepository                              $userRepository,
        UserService                                 $userService,
        TokenService                                $tokenService,
        SupplierService                             $supplierService,
        SupplierRepository                          $supplierRepository,
        OptionRepository                            $optionRepository,
        SmtpService                                 $smtpService,
        ActionService                               $actionService,
        ActionRepository                            $actionRepository,
        BranchRepository                            $branchRepository,
        BranchService                               $branchService,
        AttachmentService                           $attachmentService,
        EventRcService                              $eventRcService,
        EventRepository                             $eventRepository,
        CommonEventListDTOMapper                    $commonEventListDTOMapper,
        CommonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper $commonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper,
        CommonProductProcessListDTOMapper           $commonProductProcessListDTOMapper,
        CommonEventDTOMapper                        $commonEventDTOMapper
    )
    {
        $this->eventProcessRepository = $eventProcessRepository;
        $this->eventProductRepository = $eventProductRepository;
        $this->historyService = $historyService;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->tokenService = $tokenService;
        $this->supplierRepository = $supplierRepository;
        $this->supplierService = $supplierService;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->optionRepository = $optionRepository;
        $this->smtpService = $smtpService;
        $this->actionService = $actionService;
        $this->actionRepository = $actionRepository;
        $this->branchRepository = $branchRepository;
        $this->branchService = $branchService;
        $this->attachmentService = $attachmentService;
        $this->eventRcService = $eventRcService;
        $this->eventRepository = $eventRepository;
        $this->commonEventListDTOMapper = $commonEventListDTOMapper;
        $this->commonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper = $commonProductProcessListOutOfAuditDTOMapper;
        $this->commonProductProcessListDTOMapper = $commonProductProcessListDTOMapper;
        $this->commonEventDTOMapper = $commonEventDTOMapper;
```

Comment: This isn't helpful, but it's design advice... If one service needs that many dependencies, you're doing something very wrong. Your services have "too many responsibilities" and are not particularly "cohesive".

Comment: Do your child services have constructors?  If so please post an example.  And while unrelated is there a specific reason for setting autoconfigure false?  Seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Cerad I figured out that if I have aconstructor in a child class it overrides the parent constructor. I'm not able to put parent::_construct() because it asks for all the dependencies in the signature. But I still need to be able to use a constructor in the children classes because they have their own properties. I have not been able to find a way to achieve this

Comment: You could inject most of the dependencies using setter injection I suppose.  But as already pointed out you have far too many dependencies which implies your classes are doing too much.  Having to repeat the service configuration for all of your child classes is a minor problem compared to your class design.

Comment: ok using setter injection was the way to go. Thanks

Comment: I know you probably don't want to do a major refactoring.  I'm guessing this is legacy code?  But for pairs like `SupplierService SupplierRepository`, it seems like the service should already have access to the repository so injecting both seems like a waste.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: That's actually a code base i recently started working with, but yeah probably the CommonService can be refactored to follow SOLID principles